# Is the DRM protection for PDF's just the password?

Tags: pdf, open-source, drm, password-protection, copy-protection

I wonder if I can open a DRM protected PDF file with an open-source utility. Is it enough to type the password when requested (command line parameter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDFs can have two passwords: one for viewing the PDF, other to remove protections like copy-protection, etc.

From the tags of your question I assume you want to remove the protections like copy-protection, etc. And I assume that you know that you shouldn't circunvent copyright, etc etc.

If your open-source utility is able to accept both passwords, so yes, you could remove the protection to be able to copy something from the pdf. In general those programs just accept one password, the viewing one.

Comment: I don't want to remove any protection. I ask if the DRM prevents the PDF file from being viewed with open-source applications or other applications different from Adobe Digital Editions. I read that Adobe DRM PDF file can be read just with Adobe Digital Editions. Is it true?

Comment: Ok, got it. PDFs with DRM from adobe use something called ADEPT and only some readers are able to deal with it. I don't know any open source program that can read it. In the net you can find explanations on how to circunvent that Adobe ADEPT protection, but that would be piracy, I think.